# How to choose and limit upload and download speed for OS X Yosemite 10.10.5

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, mac

I need directions on how to do this. This is **not** a duplicate question. As the answers given in the links before are all outdated and from either 2012 or an Xcode that doesn't support this format. I need steps that are **currently working** for this model. In my App store there is only insanely high updated versions of Xcode so idk.

Answer (score 1):

Go to [Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/) and log in with your Apple ID. Then open *See more downloads* near the bottom of the page. Search for **Hardware** and download *Hardware IO Tools for Xcode 7.3*. The Hardware IO Tools for Xcode 6.3-7.3 all contain the same Network Link Conditioner 2.0 pref pane which should work at least in 10.9-10.11. The newest IO Tools are still recommended because AFAIK they contain newer certs.

Open the downloaded dmg, double-click and install *Network Link Conditioner.prefPane* for all users.

Open the pref pane in System Preferences and determine an appropriate UL/DL speed.

Comment: I have 40mbps downlink bandwidth... Downlink delay: 1ms..... uplink bandwidth 33 mbps.. uplink delay 1ms on wifi... I made a new custom profile named "dog" lol..I have an ethernet connected from my xbox one to my macbook pro..What's a good setting to make me lag during online play, but not kick me out of matches? So in other words, worst connection possible but STILL being able to connect to others.

Comment: @jimmyneutron you need to ask a separate question for each question.